# Data source retains schema after drop and add

Tags: ssis

I have several packages that are almost identical. Differ only by columns added/removed in different database versions. When I copy a package and modify the data flow of the copy, I delete the OLE DB Data Source and add a new one. Once the new one is defined, its preview shows exactly what I expect. Columns, however, are from the OLE DB source that was deleted. It's like it is being cached somewhere.

Seems like I need to close the package and re-open it after removing the data source. Is there some other way to clear this cached state? What's going on internally that causes this to happen?

More... it looks like it's the parametrized connection manager that is holding on to previous parameters until the package is closed and re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your work flow, you are copy and pasting packages and then tweaking the source definition in the data flow. The challenge is that the CustomerID in one system is varchar(7) and defined as varchar(12) in another. The "trick" becomes having the design engine recognize the metadata change and behave accordingly.

My usual hack is radically change the source. I find using the query `SELECT 1 as foo` does the trick. After doing that, the metadata for the OLE DB Source component drops all references to existing columns which percolates to the downstream components. I then switch back to the proper source and double click the first red X to have it map the IDs from old to new.

If you want a more brain surgical route than civil war surgery, change the column name in your source for anything that should have registered a metadata change. Thus `SELECT T.MyColumn, T.IsFine FROM dbo.MyTable AS T` becomes `SELECT T.MyColumnX, T.IsFine FROM dbo.MyTable AS T` Now only the first column gets kiboshed throughout the dataflow. Reset it back to the "right" column name and all is well.

Internally, I don't know but that never stops me from guessing. The Validation fires off, the SSIS Engine recognizes that the data types are still compatible so it doesn't change the existing metadata. A column no longer existing is enough to make it sit up and take notice and so the cached sizing goes away.

Some folks like to try and use the Advanced properties to change the sizes but I find I have better success just using the above approach than changing the size only to have the Designer slap my hand and disallow my proposed changes.

Comment: It's actually showing columns that are not in the current table but exist in the original. what's disorienting is that Preview shows the correct schema.

Comment: I like this solution. Simple and effective.